# How to open and read the two files at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to open the two files and pass into the another function but it is not work.

```
$.get('fasta', function (file) {
var filedata = file;
var seq = filedata.replace(/[\n\s]/g,"");
var seqpass = new seqleng(seq);
}, 'text');

$.get('pattern', function (patt) {
var pattern = patt;
var seqpass = new seqleng(pattern);
}, 'text');

function seqleng(seqfile,pattern){
alert(seqfile);
alert(pattern); 
}
```

My problem is two files are passed into the `function seqleng (seqfile)`.

I need to pass the first file into `seqfile` and second file into the `pattern`? How can i do it?

Comment: the calls are asyc. you cant read them at the same time and pass into a function, you'd need to fire the second `$.get` once the first one has returned, then pass both responses into a function on the second return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery deferred mechanism described here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

```
var r1 = $.get('fasta');
var r2 = $.get('pattern');

function seqleng(seqfile,pattern){
   alert(seqfile);
   alert(pattern); 
}

$.when(r1, r2).done(function(seqResponse, patternResponse) {
    var filedata = seqResponse[0],
        seq = filedata.replace(/[\n\s]/g,"");
    var seqpass = new seqleng(seq, patternResponse[0]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answering can you explain `seqResponse[0]  patternResponse[0]` what is the meaning of `[0]`

Comment: It described with last example from the API page: Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]. So you need only data, and you should use first element of this array i.e zero element

Answer (score 0):

As the calls are async, you don't know when they'll return. You'd could nest the calls so that the second call and finally the combining function is called once both return. i.e.

```
$.get('fasta', function (file) {
  var filedata = file;
  var seq = filedata.replace(/[\n\s]/g,"");

  $.get('pattern', function (patt) {
    var pattern = patt;
    var seqpass = new seqleng(pattern);

    seqleng(seq, seqpass);

  }, 'text');

}, 'text');



function seqleng(seqfile,pattern){
  alert(seqfile);
  alert(pattern); 
}
```

Comment: @Panoptik is the better answer. use that, not this

Comment: i used the Panoptik answer. But learn idea from your answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this isn't working is because of the *Asynchronous callbacks*.

That means that some code can be executed before the first function finished processing.

That being said, there are two commonly used ways of solving this particular issue.

1. Execute the second function within the scope of the first, as described by atmd
2. Store the results in a variable and check if they're both defined

I will post a short example of how to do it the 2nd way, as atmd already described the first option

```
var seqfile,pattern;

$.get('fasta', function (file) {
  var filedata = file;
  seqfile = filedata.replace(/[\n\s]/g,"");
  performActionIfDone();
}, 'text');

$.get('pattern', function (patt) {
  pattern = patt;
  performActionIfDone();
}, 'text');

function performActionIfDone() {
  if (seqfile && pattern) { // they're both defined, do something here
    alert(seqfile);
    alert(pattern); 
  }
}
```

An advantage of this method over #1 is that they execute at the same time. Let's say both your calls would take 10 seconds to process, it would mean that the time wasted waiting for it to be done would be 20 seconds. This is because you execute your second call after the first one returns.

If you use method #2 both will execute at the same time, and your time lost waiting would be no longer than 10 seconds.